# Can't read value from dynamically generated Radio Button list

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do this:

1. read multiple values from Windows registry (works). This looks like

   ```
   \HKLM\...\Server1
   int serverid 1
   string serverName "SRVSQL01"
   int serverport 1433
   string database "MyDatabase1"

   \HKLM\...\Server2
   dword/int serverid 2
   regsz/string serverName "SRVSQL02"
   dword/int serverport 1433
   regsz/string database "MyDatabase2"
   ```

   The number of servers can vary.
2. List items. I can read the values from the registry, this works fine
3. Add values to multiple instances of a C# class (works)

   I created a class "SQLServer" with 4 variables/values, as displayed above.
   Then I create an array of multiple instances of this class, for example if there are 4 servers listed in the registry, I generate an array with length 4 and add the value of each server to its own entity of this class.

   ```
   public class RegSQLListItem
   {
       public int MSSSQLID;
       public string MSSQLServer;
       public int MSSQLPort;
       public string MSSQLDatabase;
   }
   ```
4. display the list in a new Form by generating radio buttons, based on the number of "items" in an array.

   I found some code here to dynamically generate a list of radio buttons with labels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwafxk44(v=vs.90).aspx

   ```
   // Generate form
   int ProjectCounter = (RegProjectRoot.GetSubKeyNames()).Count();
   // other code
   RadioButton[] radioButtons = new RadioButton[ProjectCounter];
   for (int i = 0; i < ProjectCounter; ++i)
   {
       radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
       radioButtons[i].TabIndex = i + 1;
       radioButtons[i].Name = ProjectListItem[i].MSSQLDatabase;
       radioButtons[i].Text = ProjectListItem[i].MSSQLDatabase;
       radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
       this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
   }
   ```

How can I capture which radio button is selected and how to I transfer the corresponding value to another routine in my program?

I'm particularly interested in clicking an "OK" button to capture the value of the currently active radio button and so select which database I want to connect to.

Is this a correct way to do this at all or is there an easier way?
I'm new to C#, so I'm not that familiar with the possibilities.

Comment: I have added an answer below. let me know will it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

**1.** Add event handler like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ProjectCounter; ++i)
{
    radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
    radioButtons[i].TabIndex = i + 1;
    radioButtons[i].Name = "ProjectListItem[i].MSSQLDatabase";
    radioButtons[i].Text = "ProjectListItem[i].MSSQLDatabase";
    radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
    radioButtons[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rdo_CheckedChanged);
    this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
}
```

And the Handler `rdo_CheckedChanged` will defined like the following:

```
private static void rdo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdoButton = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rdoButton.Checked)
    { 
       // procced the button is checked
    }
}
```

**2.** Iterate through controls of type `RadioButton`

You can iterate through the controls and identify the selected radio button by using the following code:

```
foreach (RadioButton rdo in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if (rdo.Checked)
    {
        // this is checked radio button
        // Proceed with your code
    }
}
```